# I'm stuck on this beginners python challenge

Tags: python

I've tried everything I could but this code won't work.

I'm attempting to create a calculator that multiplies strings and integers with 2 inputs. For example I say I want "what" to multiply "5" times it should come up with whatwhatwhatwhatwhat. But all I get is an error.

here is my code :

```
what = input('What do you want me to say? ')
how = input('How many times do you want me to say it? ')
whats = int('what')
print(whats*how)
```

Comment: `int('what')` will throw error.  You can try `print(what*int(how))`

Comment: `print(what*int(how))` Notice that `how` is **how many times** and `what` is **what to say**. You swapped those two things.

Answer (score 3):

```
what=input("enter the string to multiply")
how=int(input("how many times do you want to multiply it?"))
print(what*how)
```

---

You almost got it right. All you need to fix is the second line of your code it should take the input in "int" format. You can multiply a string with an integer (number) only.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far? You are almost there.

```
what = input('What do you want me to say? ')
how = int(input('How many times do you want me to say it?'))
print(what*how)
```

By converting the how to an integer you make it a number. Then you can just use the what times the integer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a minor error in the line `whats = int('what')`. The issue is that you're trying to convert the string `'what'` to an integer, which is not valid. Instead, you should directly use the variable `what` and convert `how` to an integer. Try this:

```py
what = input('What do you want me to say? ')
how = input('How many times do you want me to say it? ')
how_many = int(how)  # Technically, you do not need to store this in an
                     # intermediary variable, but it is a good practice while 
                     # learning, to understand more easily what is happening.
print(what * how_many)
```

**Example Usage:**

```
What do you want me to say? Saiteja Nalamati is learning Python
How many times do you want me to say it? 2
Saiteja Nalamati is learning PythonSaiteja Nalamati is learning Python
```

Answer (score 0):

```
what = input('What do you want me to say? ')
how = input('How many times do you want me to say it? ')
whats = int(what)
print(whats * int(how))
#this should be the correct code
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression whats =int(what) will raise an error as you are trying to convert an incompatible string to int type. The correct code will be:

what=input("What do you want me to say?")

how=int(input("How many times do you want me to say it?"))

print(what*how)

Answer (score -1):

`'what'` is not a string containing an integer, so you can't convert it to an integer with `int()`. You should be converting the variable `how` to an integer.

Then you need to multiply the variable `what`, which contains the string you want to duplicate, by that integer.

Use better variable names so you will not get confused about what each variable contains.

```
what = input('What do you want me to say? ')
howmany = int(input('How many times do you want me to say it? '))
print(what*howmany)
```

Answer (score -1):

You were almost there. In order to fix your code, I converted user input in `how` to integer, then declared a variable `result` and assigned `what*how` to it. Finally, I printed `result`.

```
what = input('What do you want me to say? ')
how = int(input('How many times do you want me to say it? '))
result = what*how
print(result)
```